# Would the negation of Russell's axiom of infinity serve this purpose?

Tags: first-order-logic

For any positive integer n, we can construct a sentence Ψ_n in FOL such that an interpretation        I ⊨ Ψ_n iff the domain of I has exactly n elements. Suppose we wanted to construct a sentence Φ  such that an interpretation I ⊨  Φ iff the domain of I is finite. Would the negation of Russell's axiom of infinity serve this purpose?

Comment: It cannot be done. If $\Phi$ can be satisfied by arbitrarily large finite $I$, then compactness means there’s an infinite structure that satisfies it.

Comment: @MaliceVidrine That should be an answer.

Answer (score 1):

As I mention in my comment, not only will the negation of the axiom of infinity not do the trick, nothing will. If $\Phi$ is satisfied by arbitrarily large finite $I$ (and you certainly want there to be arbitrarily large such $I$ if $I\vDash\Phi$ is to mean "$I$ is finite") then the compactness theorem tells us that $\Phi$ will be satisfied by some infinite structure.